# Magento 2 Rest API partial shipment

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api

I am trying to use the Rest API to create partial shipments for Magneto 2 orders.  In two different scenarios.

First is one item with multiple pieces, say a customer ordered 4 pieces of sku 3 but I only ship 1 piece.  I send the message to

https://test.m2.test.com/index.php/rest/V1/order/61845/ship

with body

{"entity":{"order_id":"61845","items":[{"order_item_id":"3","qty":"1"}]}}

I get a valid response "44360" but when I check the order in the admin I see

Ordered 4

Shipped 4.

I have tried the message with just the items

{"entity":{"items":[{"order_item_id":"3","qty":"1"}]}}

and with actual item id

{"entity":{"order_id":"61845","items":[{"order_item_id":"77130","qty":"1"}]}}

{"entity":{"items":[{"order_item_id":"77130","qty":"1"}]}}

every one of them yields the same result

Ordered 4

Shipped 4.

The second scenario is with multiple items in the order; if I ship one item but not the other both are shown as fully shipped.

It basically appears that the application is just seeing the order_id in the POST path and marks everything in that order as shipped in full.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For partial shipments you can use the following webservice:

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesShipmentRepositoryV1/salesShipmentRepositoryV1SavePost

**/rest/V1/shipment**
[image]

The only set back is that you will have to update the qty_shipped of your order_item manually. For that you can use the order repository.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1SavePost

let me know if you need any further assistance !

Comment: That was very helpful and helped resolve my issue.  I have run into a similar thing with invoices as well; are partial invoices possible with authorize.net?

Comment: I don't use authorize.net . I use this webservice, https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesInvoiceRepositoryV1

You can invoice a partial amount but you have to pass a lot of information into the webservice in order to it correctly.